# How to embed a React app into another website without the use of Iframe,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load a quiz app build in react into another website within DIV of size 300x600. I cannot use iframes or embed tag.
Website i want to embed - https://quiztwiz.com/
code - https://demos.unibots.in/quiz/quiz.html

I tired running npm run build.
Tried running the js and css file on the website i want to show the app.also made a #root div to load the react app into it.

If you can show this https://quiztwiz.com/ site on another website in a div of size 300x600. Please do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I had suggest having Webpack bundle your component with whatever dependencies you need into a standalone js file. Then rather than using a typical app.js / index.js file that attaches an app to a body or  tag like create-react-app does, specifically use "ReactDOM" to render your component to a specific div based on ID. That way they just include your file and make sure they have the div with the ID and it'll take care of the rest.

```html
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from 'my-component.js';
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, '#my-div');
```